# T/F: If $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ are irreducible polynomials that have the same splitting field, then deg $f=$ deg $g$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

This is a true or false problem, and I think it is true, but I am not entirely sure if my thought process is correct. Some of my thought process is that since $f$ is irreducible and let's say it is of degree $n$, then the splitting field of $f$ is also of degree $n$. Since both $f$ and $g$ are irreducible, and they have the same splitting field, both should be the same degree.
Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: You should really tell us what you *do* know, or what examples you have attempted (if any). Otherwise, we don’t know how to cast adequate hints that might be helpful, and we could just tell you things that are not appropriate or are totally confusing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have updated the post, sorry about that.

Comment: Adding a single root gives you an extension of degree $n$; but you have reason to know that adding a single root will yield the splitting field. Maybe it does, maybe it doesn’t. Can you think of examples where it does and ones where it doesn’t? (So “the splitting field of $f$ is also of degree $n$” is not necessarily correct....)

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Take $f = x^3 - 2$. This is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive third root of unity. Then the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta)$. Now, take $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2} + \zeta$. Then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta) = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$. The degree of the extension is $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta) : \mathbb Q] = 6$. Hence, the degree of the minimal polynomial $g$ of $\alpha$ is also 6. As $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta) / \mathbb Q$ is a normal extension and $g$ has a root in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta)$, it must split in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta)$. Hence, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta)$ is a splitting field of both $f$ and $g$, which are both irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Q$. However, $deg(f) = 3 \neq 6 = deg(g)$.